# using generic and for each loop in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am developing a web application.  I am using Eclipse as IDE.  I was using generic and for each loop, both being feature of java 1.5, and it compiled quite fine when used in backend means in simple java classes.  But when I'm using these on jsp, jsp is failing to compile with error showing generic and for each as culprit.  Can you shed some light on this?  Maybe I am at fault with Eclipse settings?

Comment: Wait while I hack your computer, connect to your hard drive, read the code you're trying to compile and identify error.

Comment: @Nikita Rybak: +1 for sarcasm

Comment: You should not use java code in JSPs. WE did that 10 years ago. It sucked, so we stopped doing it.

Comment: I did it 6 years ago. It still sucked :)

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody for ur valuable comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had this problem before on WebSphere I believe. The web containers use certain default versions of the Java source level for compiling jsp's. Below is how you modify that

Tomcat: http://www.giannistsakiris.com/index.php/2007/09/19/apache-tomcat-to-compile-java-5-jsps/

WebSphere: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21264609

JBOSS: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBWEB-87

Comment: Thanks a lot of for the answer buddy.Though problem persist at least I got a glimpse what is happening.Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the JSTL tag library.  The forEach tag should do what you need nicely.

[JSTL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html)